# Multiple PHPSESSID collisions

Tags: php, session

I have noticed that multiple users per day are being assigned the same session_id. I am using **php 7.2** now, but looking back into the history of user sessions this has been happening since I was using **php 5.4**.

I am just using php defaults of `session_start()`, no custom session handler.

I have read that the `session_id` is a combo of the client ip and time, but give that I am using a load balancer, that might be limiting the randomness of the `ip_addresses`?

What is the proper way to increase the uniqueness of session_ids to prevent collisions when using a load balancer?

Comment: Where did you read that session ids were based on ip addresses and time? That would be a horrible practice. IPs can change between page loads. They are just randomly generated strings with nothing to do with any identifying data.

Comment: Actually, to use a load balancer with more than one server behind it, you do need some sort of session handler to store them in a database, key/value store or I guess you could change the php.ini config to store to a central file system. And I guess there are sticky sessions. If you are just using session_start and no handler, then there has to be some changes in your php.ini file that affect sessions. Can you run a phpinfo() page and post the relevant session config information or let us know what you are using?.

Comment: "I guess you could change the php.ini config to store to a central file system" with Heroku, they have an Ephemeral file system so this wouldn't be possible. I do not think... who is your host OP?

Comment: AWS, I think ill switch to a db or elasticache solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nginx you may want to check if FastCGI micro-caching is enabled and disable it. This has caused some errors before noted in PHP.net developers bugs listings in PHP 7.1 running nginx

> Bug #75496    Session ID Collision happened few times
>
> After the first case [of collision] we changed a hash entropy php settings in php.ini so session_id is now 48 chars but it didn't help to prevent second case.

Solution:

> FastCGI micro caching at nginx that cached 200 responses together with session cookies.
>   Of course maybe it was set wrong at our server, but its definitely has nothing to do with PHP.

Please see:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75496

Comment: Thank you for this, but im using apache

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running PHP-FPM on each web node, but I guess #2 and #3 would probably work running PHP as an Apache plugin as well.

You've got a few options here:

1. Keep your LB'd web nodes with apache and have each one point to the same upstream PHP-FPM server. Obviously the third box running the single PHP-FPM process might need to be beefier, since it's handling PHP parsing for both web nodes.
2. Change the session storage to point to a file location (probably a NFS or SMB share) that both servers can access. Not sure if I've ever done this honestly but it seems like it would work. Really, your web files should probably be on an NFS/SMB share already so you can deploy changes to only one location.
3. Spin up a redis server and have both web nodes' PHP-FPM process use that for session.

Number three is probably the best option in most cases.